# No module named scipy even though it is installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, scipy

I am trying to use scipy but when I import it with `import scipy`, it says "no module named scipy. I have used `pip list` to see if it is installed and it is, and i have tried `pip install scipy` but it just said that it was already installed. Does anyone know how to fix this?

SOLVED: ran the code with python3 instead of python

Comment: Do you have two (or more) different versions of Python installed? The usual problem here is that your pip command is associated with a different version of Python than what you’re using to run code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible you have 2 versions of python installed, python2.7 or python3.x .. when you install stuff with pip and want to use it for a specific python version:

pip install scipy is for python 2.7, so its "python" in the terminal and "python x" to run scripts

pip3 install scipy is for python 3, so its "python3" in the terminal and "python3 x" to run scripts

in your case, you would be calling scripts like:
python pythonFile.py

you would be installing packages like:
pip install package

and you would be using python in the terminal with "python"

if that still doesn't work, for me solving that problem was updating numpy. not sure if it would be the same with you. hope this helped